# Logstash on Docker using JDBC input plugin does not fetch all rows from SQL Server

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-jdbc

I'm trying to index data into Elasticsearch 7.8.0 from SQL Server through Logstash 7.8.0. All works well when I use non docker version of Logstash.

I have more than 6 million rows I need to fetch and the count matches exactly. But when I run the same configuration with Logstash on Docker (official image), it only fetches a few rows (~ 3500) and then stops. There is no error in logs.

I have tried running various SQL queries. Depending on number of columns I try to ingest, the no of rows vary. For e.g. if I select only 1 column e.g `ID`, more rows will be imported (~ 8000) but it never fetches all of them. Also, when I use non-docker version, the logstash shuts down once it finished fetching all 6 million+ rows. But in non-docker version, it just stops without shutdown. I waited for 30 mins, but no more data is fetched.

Below is my sample logstash.conf

```html
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:sqlserver://<ip>:<port>;databaseName=<dbname>;"
    jdbc_user => "<user>"
    jdbc_password => "<password>" 
    statement => "SELECT id from <table> WHERE id is NOT NULL"
  }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["https://<elastichost>:9200"] 
        index => "my_index"
        document_id => "%{id}"
    }
    stdout {
      codec => rubydebug
    }
}
```

and here is the log

```html
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.headius.backport9.modules.Modules (file:/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/jars/jruby-complete-9.2.11.1.jar) to method sun.nio.ch.NativeThread.signal(long)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.headius.backport9.modules.Modules
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Sending Logstash logs to /usr/share/logstash/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[2020-07-30T23:40:13,897][INFO ][logstash.setting.writabledirectory] Creating directory {:setting=>"path.queue", :path=>"/usr/share/logstash/data/queue"}
[2020-07-30T23:40:13,906][INFO ][logstash.setting.writabledirectory] Creating directory {:setting=>"path.dead_letter_queue", :path=>"/usr/share/logstash/data/dead_letter_queue"}
[2020-07-30T23:40:14,110][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"7.8.0", "jruby.version"=>"jruby 9.2.11.1 (2.5.7) 2020-03-25 b1f55b1a40 OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 11.0.7+10-LTS on 11.0.7+10-LTS +indy +jit [linux-x86_64]"}
[2020-07-30T23:40:14,123][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] No persistent UUID file found. Generating new UUID {:uuid=>"d96a0289-4426-425c-a17f-81de075598cb", :path=>"/usr/share/logstash/data/uuid"}
[2020-07-30T23:40:15,306][INFO ][org.reflections.Reflections] Reflections took 23 ms to scan 1 urls, producing 21 keys and 41 values 
[2020-07-30T23:40:15,791][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] ** WARNING ** Detected UNSAFE options in elasticsearch output configuration!
** WARNING ** You have enabled encryption but DISABLED certificate verification.
** WARNING ** To make sure your data is secure change :ssl_certificate_verification to true
[2020-07-30T23:40:16,062][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[https://user:xxxxxx@elastichost:9200/]}}
[2020-07-30T23:40:16,341][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Restored connection to ES instance {:url=>"https://user:xxxxxx@elastichost:9200/"}
[2020-07-30T23:40:16,370][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] ES Output version determined {:es_version=>7}
[2020-07-30T23:40:16,372][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Detected a 6.x and above cluster: the `type` event field won't be used to determine the document _type {:es_version=>7}
[2020-07-30T23:40:16,386][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] New Elasticsearch output {:class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch", :hosts=>["https://elastichost:9200"]}
[2020-07-30T23:40:16,440][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>16, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>50, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>2000, "pipeline.sources"=>["/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf"], :thread=>"#<Thread:0x4f6117d run>"}
[2020-07-30T23:40:16,449][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Using default mapping template
[2020-07-30T23:40:16,468][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Attempting to install template {:manage_template=>{"index_patterns"=>"logstash-*", "version"=>60001, "settings"=>{"index.refresh_interval"=>"5s", "number_of_shards"=>1}, "mappings"=>{"dynamic_templates"=>[{"message_field"=>{"path_match"=>"message", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false}}}, {"string_fields"=>{"match"=>"*", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false, "fields"=>{"keyword"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "ignore_above"=>256}}}}}], "properties"=>{"@timestamp"=>{"type"=>"date"}, "@version"=>{"type"=>"keyword"}, "geoip"=>{"dynamic"=>true, "properties"=>{"ip"=>{"type"=>"ip"}, "location"=>{"type"=>"geo_point"}, "latitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}, "longitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}}}}}}}
[2020-07-30T23:40:17,184][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Pipeline started {"pipeline.id"=>"main"}
[2020-07-30T23:40:17,229][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Pipelines running {:count=>1, :running_pipelines=>[:main], :non_running_pipelines=>[]}
[2020-07-30T23:40:17,382][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
[2020-07-30T23:40:19,279][INFO ][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ][main][598a8fa14ff28545975bda9c2337080827010b1648613a0fb1dca648ce4fd53a] (0.401349s) SELECT ID from table WHERE ID is NOT NULL
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/awesome_print-1.7.0/lib/awesome_print/formatters/base_formatter.rb:31: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
{
            "id"[0;37m => [0m[0;33m"A7A5F8F0-7873-4786-84AC-000023B5A705"[0m,
    "@timestamp"[0;37m => [0m2020-07-30T23:40:19.317Z,
      "@version"[0;37m => [0m[0;33m"1"[0m
}
{
            "id"[0;37m => [0m[0;33m"142FEDDF-49C7-41B3-978E-000048A8C2FC"[0m,
    "@timestamp"[0;37m => [0m2020-07-30T23:40:19.319Z,
      "@version"[0;37m => [0m[0;33m"1"[0m
}
```

Comment: have you messed with the [fetch size](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html#plugins-inputs-jdbc-jdbc_fetch_size) or the [paging configs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html#plugins-inputs-jdbc-jdbc_page_size)?

Comment: No, I did not. I have not set the values explicitly as you can see from my logstash.conf above. I'm using mssql-jdbc-8.2.0.jre11 as JDBC driver.